# How to import tickets into OSTicket

Tags: mysql, php, import

I am trying to import tickets from a CSV file into OSTicket. I searched in the forums but they keep recommending Professional support.

Is there a way to import them for free? Maybe into the database?

Code editing is suggested in this thread: https://forum.osticket.com/d/75875-ability-to-import-from-excel-sheet-or-csv

Has anyone done it?

Comment: Why is this Question tagged [mysql] and [csv]?  If you can get to MySQL, use `LOAD DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

OSTicket does not currently have any feature or plugin that does this, this is why professional support is being recommended. OSTicket does have an API which you could use to automate ticket creation: https://docs.osticket.com/en/latest/Developer%20Documentation/API%20Docs.html

Answer (score 0):

The key tables you will want to focus on for an import of tickets from an external system are **ost_ticket** and **ost_ticket__cdata** tables. For ost_ticket you will need to look through the fields and see what's relevant for you; for ost_ticket__cdata the id's need to match in both tables and you just dump the ticket subject into the ost_ticket__cdata table.

The other two relevant fields are **user_id** and **user_email_id**. Those reference the **ost_user** and **ost_user_email** tables.